# Vlookup with joint parameters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've a list of categories and there descriptions, and in another sheet I receive the categories as `join` field, and want to display the descriptions beside them, in the below screen shoot, I need the yellow shaded field to appear as shown:

[image]

I split the joint categories using:

```
=split(G6,",")
```

And was able to get the description of each one individually, but once I tried to do the `vlookup` with the split as below, it failed and made vlookup for the first element only,

```
=vlookup(split(G6,","),P:Q,2,false)
```

How can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to array-enable the vlookup and then join the results. See if this helps

```
=join(",", ArrayFormula(vlookup(split(G6, ",", 0), P:Q, 2, 0)))
```

[image: Example]

If you want to array-enable this solution, so that you have a single formula processing the range G6:G, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(transpose(query(transpose(if(len(G6:G), iferror(vlookup(split(G6:G, ",", 0), P:Q, 2, 0)&","),)),,rows(G6:G))), ",$",))
```

```
=ArrayFormula(          // to run over all the rows in the same column
    regexreplace(       // to remove double "nothing"
        regexreplace(   // to remove the training "/"
            transpose(
                query( // to make the data in single row
                    transpose(
                        if(
                            len(E2:E), 
                            iferror(
                            vlookup(
                                split(E2:E, ",", 0), 
                                IMPORTRANGE("11STqPDOM7YMZxrvCySQSUzC8GEzgUZIVDZDX_l3pzJw","Data!A:B"), 2, 0)
                            &char(10), )  // char(10) for new line / carriage after each line
                        ,"nothing") // if nothing to split
                    )
                    ,,rows(E2:E)
                )   //  a trick to create a single row with data
            )
        , "^[\r\n]+|\.|[\r\n]+$",)    // to remove the trailing carriage / newline "/"
    , "(nothing)\s",)   // to remove double "nothing"
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, but failed once I put it inside a `arrayformula` this code `=ARRAYFORMULA(join(",", ArrayFormula(vlookup(split(G3:G5, ",", 0), P:Q, 2, 0))))` gave me an error `Did not find value '' in VLOOKUP evaluation`

Comment: join() can't be iterated over an array. If you want to use the provided formula in an array, take a look a the second formula i posted above.

Comment: Thanks, can you some explanation in the code, specially the first 3 blocks `   regexreplace(transpose(query(` and the usage of `rows(E2:E)` in the query statement, moreover if there is nothing to split, I'm getting 2 error not one, I added screen shoot to your answer to make it clear.

Comment: Hi the rows(E2:E) constitutes the rows argument in query. It's basically a trick to create a single row with data. That row is then transposed to create a column in the output. The regexreplace just removes the trailing comma (or: " / " in the adapted formule). To avoid having "nothing nothing' you can add another regexreplace to removes the first occurence of 'nothing'. New formula: =ArrayFormula(regexreplace(regexreplace(transpose(query(transpose(if(len(G6:G), iferror(vlookup(split(G6:G, ",", 0), P:Q, 2, 0)&" / ", "nothing"),)),,rows(G6:G))), "\s/\s$",), "(nothing)\s",)). Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks, that's really great, appreciated a lot.

Comment: Can you give some insight about the usage of both `transpose`?